# Prevent AdvancedFilter xFilterCopy to copy formulas from source

Tags: vba, excel

Im facing a little trouble with AdvancedFilter xFilterCopy method. I am trying to copy from a range with unique values into another cell. But the issue is when copying along with values its copying the formulas in the source cells. That causing trouble in destination cell

Here is my code to copy. Its copying without any trouble. But on the new pasted cell it looks like `#REF!`. On checking the cell what I found is it copied the function from source cell too.

```
xRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("Report_bar").Range("A2"), Unique:=True
```

So how can we avoid this issue and let it copy only values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `xlFilterInPlace` then copy it and paste it with `PasteSpecial` and paste only the values with `xlPasteValues`, something like this:

```
xRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
xRange.Copy
Sheets("Report_bar").Cells(2, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Hopy you didnt noticed Uniqu:=True in xFilterCopy

Comment: Oh yes I see, Sorry. Is it possible for you to `xlFilterInPlace` and then copy and `PasteSpecial` ? Edited the answer